# Chased Conduit Bend through Exterior Wall

Tags: electrical, conduit, masonry

I am in the middle of a re-wiring project, part of which requires installing new light switches on the inside of an exterior wall (plaster directly on brick). I will be installing the switch box flush to the wall surface and chasing the wall to install conduit (1/2" EMT).

One of the switches will control an exterior light which will be positioned above the switches on the exterior side of the wall. I imagine accomplishing this by a chase which extends straight above the switch box, then a 90° bend toward the external wall where I will install a surface-mounted box. My concern is the drilling depth required to install this conduit.

From what I can tell, my local code (based on the 2018 IRC) only provides restrictions on "chases and recesses," though these terms are not specifically defined. As I have no horizontal chases or chases wider than 12", I believe the only relevant restriction is the depth (not more than 1/3 wall thickness, corresponding to about 2.75" in my case):

> Chases and recesses in masonry walls shall not be deeper than
> one-third the wall thickness. The maximum length of a horizontal chase
> or horizontal projection shall not exceed 4 feet (1219 mm) and shall
> have not less than 8 inches(203 mm) of masonry in back of the chases
> and recesses and between adjacent chases or recesses and the jambs of
> openings.Chases and recesses in masonry walls shall be designed and
> constructed so as not to reduce the required strength or required fire
> resistance of the wall and shall not be permitted within the required
> area of a pier. Masonry directly above chases or recesses wider than
> 12 inches (305 mm) shall be supported on noncombustible lintels.

The bend will have the minimum 4" radius, so over a length of around 2-4", the chase will be deeper than the maximum before transitioning to a hole. I do not see any specific restrictions on holes drilled in masonry wall in my code. **Does the 90° bend into the wall to the exterior violate the code restrictions on chase or recess depth?** The alternative is to use an intermediate junction box in the interior wall, but it would need to remain accessible and therefore visible (not what I want). I do not believe I can use 90° pull elbow and bury it in the wall at the end.